# Getting an 404 error after deploying web project to Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, request-mapping

I am trying to build an example for educational purposes with `Spring MVC`and `Hibernate`.

I use `IntelliJ`, `Maven` and `Tomcat7`. I am trying to do a simple requestmapping so when `localhost:8080` loads it will show `hello.jsp` (a simple hello - nothing special).

However I get an `404` error. I configured `Tomcat7` in `IntelliJ` andset Application context `/` and my web folder to be deploedy at server startup

[image]

I have organize my files in that way:

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>WebAgg</groupId>
    <artifactId>webagg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">



    <display-name>Spring Hibernate JPA Hello World Application</display-name>

    <!-- Configuration file for the root application context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">



    <!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aggric"/>

    <!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This resolves messages from resource bundles for different locales -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>


    <!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory;
      rather than application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aggric.model" />
        <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
             Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
  configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://147.27.60.195:5432/Aggric_postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access.
    JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
    </bean>

    <!-- responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power annotation-driven transaction management;
         such as when @Transactional methods are invoked -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />



</beans>
```

IndexController

```
package com.aggric.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String SayHello(){

        return "hello";


    }
}
```

Any suggestions of what I am missing?

Comment: Any exception maybe?

Comment: no exception.At event log Compilation completed successfully in 5 sec and Artifact WebAgg: Artifact is deployed successfully

Comment: try `localhost:8080/webagg`

Comment: at web.xml i set <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> so when i run project the browser appears with localhost:8080 a 404 errorr and doesn't load hello jsp as requestmapping defines

Comment: Try this: localhost:8080/WebAggr/hello.jsp

Comment: Turn on your Spring logging. I bet you'll see Spring's context initialization fail.

Answer (score 2):

On Tomcat the application is deployed to

```
hostname:port/application-name
```

Just because you set the URL pattern to `/` it won't deploy it as a root application. For that, you need to create a `ROOT.war` and deploy it.

But I would not advise this. If you would like a simpler URL for outside access, use a reverse proxy, not abuse Tomcat.

Comment: i add at pom.xml <packaging>war</packaging> and at intellij tomcat edit i set (at 1st photo) artifact build and i choose the WebAgg:war artifact.Is that you told me or i understood wrong

Comment: I don't know IDEA, but most likely yes. Anyway, this should be the correct url: `localhost:8080/WebAggr` if IDEA deploys as Eclipse would (with the project name)

Comment: They also set their application context to `/` in their IDE configuration. This is not the issue.

Comment: As you see at 1st photo Deploy at  server startup.I delete that option and i create new artifact(green cross).Then i choose artifact and the war file.Its ok now.That you see at 1st photo is the folder that my project is and not the war file.

Answer (score -1):

Where do you tell spring to scan your com.aggric.controller package in order to find your controller?
In my SpringBoot application I have my main class annotated by a

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

I think there should be a similar directive somewher in your bean configurations.

Comment: He does have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` there. So this is a moot point.